# Email Validation with AngularJS 1.2.0

Tags: angularjs, email, email-validation

I'm doing email validation with Angular out of box and works like must be.

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
               name="email" ng-model="user.email" required/>
        <div class="error-block" ng-if="form.$submitted && form.email.$invalid">
            <div ng-if="form.email.$error.required">Enter the Email Address</div>
            <div ng-if="form.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</div>
```

The problem is that when the user insert a domain with more than 6 characters, Angular complain about it. For instance if I try to use the email `dericlima@company.company`, Angular set the email like Invalid.

But if I set the email `dericlima@company.compan`, Angular validate the email without problems.
Do I have some way to extend the regex to more than 6 characters or I need to use `ng-pattern` ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour was fixed in angular v1.2.10.
You might either have to update to that version or use ng-patter with regular expression from [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/79e519fedaec54390a8bdacfb1926bfce57a1eb6) commit from angular repository.

Also, I'd advise you to look into this [article](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) about email regexp checking.